# installing aws php sdk - unexpected variables

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I'm trying to use the AWS php sdk, and having some issues getting set up. I'm getting this error when I run my php script that requires the autoloader:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$value' (T_VARIABLE) in /[directory path]/Aws/functions.php on line 36
```

I looked in that document, and line 36 is the one that begins with `if ($pred($value))`.

```
function filter($iterable, callable $pred){
    foreach ($iterable as $value) {
        if ($pred($value)) {
            yield $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Not really sure how to work around this, so any tips would be greatly appreciated. Things I've tried: installing with composer. installing with .zip.

Followed these steps: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/installation.html

Comment: what version of php are you running?

Comment: 5.4.37  ... according to the aws sdk readme it only requires 5.3.3+

Comment: Line 36 is probably the one with `yield`. The `yield` keyword requires php 5.5 and up. the aws sdk has different versions, newer sdk versions require a higher php version.

Comment: awesome, that totally did the trick! if you make it an answer I'd be happy to accept! Not sure why the readme that is included with this sdk version explicitly states only 5.3.3 is required, but oh well.

Comment: You are looking at the wrong documentation. Try the v3 guide: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [`yield`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php) keyword for generators requires PHP 5.5.

[Support for the last version that didn't have generators ended mid-late 2015.](http://php.net/supported-versions.php) Continuing to use anything below what is currently supported is a bad idea.
Consider bumping your PHP version.

Having said that, you may want to investigate [sdk version 2.8.8](https://packagist.org/packages/aws/aws-sdk-php#2.8.8) or lower. The 'required' sections of packagist list the php version requirements.