# Amazon SES Mail Error (including aws.phar)

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm trying to send my mail using Amazon SES. I downloaded the PHP SDK via .zip and uploaded all the files to my server. Currently, I have a web form that grabs the user's data like name and e-mail and sends a coupon from my database to their e-mail.

```
[17-Aug-2015 12:53:49 America/New_York] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$value' (T_VARIABLE) in phar:///home/public_html/coupon/inc/src/aws.phar/Aws/functions.php on line 36
```

I believe there is something wrong with the way I am including aws.phar. Does anyone with experience or has encountered this problem before tell me what's going on?

Comment: I found the issue -- it is because my server is running PHP 5.4 and the current SDK package uses functions surpassing 5.4. Using an older SDK version solved this problem.

Comment: Maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30580770/installing-aws-php-sdk-unexpected-variables